# Calculating the number of primes between 3 and another number

Tags: c++, primes

This is a simple program that gets a number from a user and calculates the number of primes between 3 and the user's number. I'm just curious if I'm using too many variables. I'm only asking since I'm used to not needing to initialize iterator variables before a loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int isPrime(int);
int main() {
    int userValue;
    int b;
    int x;
    char c;
    cout<< "Enter a number : "<< flush;
    cin >> userValue;
    for (x = 3; x <= userValue; x= x+2){
        a = isPrime(x);
        if (a == 1){ 
        b +=1;    
        }
    }
    cout << "There is, " << b << " number of primes from 3 to "<< userValue << endl;    
    cout << "hit enter to terminate..."<< flush;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();    
}

int isPrime(int number){
    int i;
    for(i=2; i<number; i++){
    if (number % i == 0 && i != number) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You didn't ask for this but you could test if an integer is a prime in a much more efficient way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I wouldn't say you're using too many variables (except for `c`, which doesn't appear to be used anywhere).  Not enough functions, though.  And perhaps too many spurious assignments.  Specifically, I'd suggest something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int);
int countPrimes(int);
int main() {
    int userValue;
    cout<< "Enter a number : "<< flush;
    cin >> userValue;

    cout << "There are, " << countPrimes(userValue) << " number of primes from 3 to "<< userValue << endl;    
    cout << "hit enter to terminate..."<< flush;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();    
}

int countPrimes(int number) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int x = 3; x <= number; x += 2){
        if (isPrime(x)){ 
            result++;    
        }
    }
    return result;
}

bool isPrime(int number){
    for(int i=2; i<number; i++){
        if (number % i == 0 && i != number) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

That will do the same thing as your code.  Also, please consider using variable names that are not just single-letters.

Comment: Thanks for catching the unused c variable. I converted this program from C program which needed a character variable for a scanf() function.

Answer (score 2):

- Do you really need `std::flush` after each output?  It does take some extra time, but fortunately it's not being used too often in this program.
- This does look like a C program, especially with `isPrime()` returning an `int` instead of a `bool`.  You would then either return `true` or `false` instead of `1` or `0`.  I see that this has already been mentioned by @aroth, but I wanted to make sure you were clear on that.
- Some of your indentation is consistent, particular inside the `for` loops.
- `std::cin.get()` technically extracts a character from the screen, not waits specifically for the user to press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

  You could instead say something more accurate like this:

  > "Enter any key and press ENTER to terminate"
- The `x= x+2` can be shortened to `x += 2`.  This is also a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are using too many variables: the compiler should have told you that `c` was unused, and you should always compile with warnings turned on.

However, it is hard to keep track of them when so many of them have one-letter names.  It would be more pleasant if you renamed `b` → `primeCount`, `x` → `primeCandidate`.

In addition, I would extract the loop into its own [`primeCount()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) function for clarity and reusability.

In `isPrime()`, the `i != number` condition is redundant, since the loop-terminating condition is `i < number`.  Actually, you could terminate earlier, at `ceil(sqrt(n))`.  However, a much more efficient way for testing the primality of many numbers is to use another algorithm, such as the [sieve-of-eratosthenes](/questions/tagged/sieve-of-eratosthenes).